# how to change variables given event in scipy's solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy, physics, ode, solver

**TLDR**

I'm using `scipy.solve_ivp` to solve `phi''(t) = a(t) - b * (phi'(t))^2` and I want to change the value of `b` whenever the sign of `phi'(t)` changes

---

**What I've Tried**

More specifically, the function represents an equation of torques on a wing with drag (not really important for the matter but still) and the entire solver is encapsulated in the following `Solver` class.

This is a runnable code, but the most important functions are `sequential_solver`, `phi_dot_zero_crossing_event` and `phi_derivatives`

```
# some constants to run the code ...
NUM_SAMPLES = 100  # every time window has this many samples
MASS = 1
WING_LENGTH = 0.07 
AERODYNAMIC_CENTER = 0.7 * WING_LENGTH
GYRATION_RADIUS = 0.6 * WING_LENGTH
MoI = MASS * GYRATION_RADIUS ** 2
AIR_DENSITY = 1.2 
WING_AREA = 0.5 * WING_LENGTH * (0.5 * WING_LENGTH) * np.pi  # 1/2 ellipse with minor radios ~ 1/2 major = length/2
C_D_MAX = 3.4
C_D_0 = 0.4
C_L_MAX = 1.8 
class Solver:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._alpha = 45

    def get_c_drag(self) -> float:
        """
        calculates the drag coefficient based on the angle of attack
        """
        return (C_D_MAX + C_D_0) / 2 - (C_D_MAX - C_D_0) / 2 * np.cos(2 * self._alpha)

    def get_c_lift(self) -> float:
        """
        calculates the lift coefficient based on the angle of attack
        """
        return C_L_MAX * np.sin(2 * self._alpha)

    def tau_z(self, t: float) -> np.float:
        """
        the moment we apply using the motors
        """
        return np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)


    def tau_drag(self, phi_dot):
        """
        the drag moment
        """
        return 0.5 * AIR_DENSITY * WING_AREA * self.get_c_drag() * (GYRATION_RADIUS ** 2) * (phi_dot ** 2)

    def phi_derivatives(self, t, y):
        """
        A function that defines the ODE that is to be solved: I * phi_ddot = tau_z - tau_drag.
        We think of y as a vector y = [phi,phi_dot]. the ode solves dy/dt = f(y,t)
        :return:
        """
        phi, phi_dot = y[0], y[1]
        dy_dt = [phi_dot, (self.tau_z(t) - self.tau_drag(phi_dot)) / MoI]  # d[phi,phi_dot]]/dt = [phi_dot,phi_ddot]
        return dy_dt

    def phi_dot_zero_crossing_event(self, t, y):
        return y[1]

    def sequential_solver(self, use_windows):
        """
        solves the ODE
        :return:
        """
        phi_0 = 2e-3
        phi_dot_0 = 0
        prev_t = 0
        start_t, end_t, delta_t = 1e-1, 5, 1e-1
        inner_delta_t = delta_t / NUM_SAMPLES

        
        time = np.arange(start_t, end_t, inner_delta_t)
        sol = solve_ivp(self.phi_derivatives, t_span=(start_t, end_t), y0=[phi_0, phi_dot_0], t_eval=time,
                            events=self.phi_dot_zero_crossing_event)
        phi, phi_dot = sol.y
        _, phi_ddot = self.phi_derivatives(time, [phi, phi_dot])
```

---

**So what's the problem?**

my question is how, given `phi_dot_zero_crossing_event`, I can change the value of `self._alpha` mid-solving? I currently only track the event of zero crossing, but I don't know how to use this event to set the value of `self._alpha` (if `phi_dot>0` I need `self._alpha = +45` and `self._alpha=-45` otherwise)

Comment: Error: NotImplementedError. There are only two event actions available in solve_ivp. "Register" happens always, and you can set `event.terminal=True` to get a "Terminate" action. You would have to use "Terminate" to interrupt the integration, set the new parameter, and restart with the last state as initial state. Loop, collect and concatenate the solution fragments if desired.

Comment: thanks, Lutz. can you refer me to some relevant code? as I'm not quite sure how how the process of terminating and restarting the simulation should be written

Comment: [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767096/odeint-returns-wrong-results-for-an-ode), while not very inspiring, contains the mentioned mechanism. A slightly more interesting [example in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309851/unsure-about-how-to-use-event-function), where the event mechanism is similar to the Scipy one.

Comment: thank you. How do you think I should ensure I cross the zero point boundary in my specific case?

Comment: I do not think that you need to take care in this specific situation. With the changed parameters only the acceleration changes, not the velocity. Thus the direction of the position changes remains constant over phase changes, getting into a sliding mode scenario seems unlikely.